# Java: If condition only being checked once

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a simple Android app in Java with the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //Declare variables
    boolean first = true;
    boolean secondorbefore = true;

        Button ClickMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clicker);

        ClickMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Check to see if this is the first click
                if (first = true) {
                first = false;
                // DO STUFF FOR FIRST CLICK
                } else if ((secondorbefore = true) {
                    //so this is the second click?
                    secondorbefore = false;
                // DO STUFF FOR SECOND CLICK                
                    } else {
                    //OK it's the third click or later
                // DO STUFF FOR THIRD OR LATER CLICKS
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

However, it only seems to run through the if condition once. It carries out the code in the first instance, including setting the secondorbefore variable to false, but subsequent clicks seem to do nothing. The code OnClickListener is being executed in subsequent clicks but it's just not running through the conditional statement.

New to Java, so I'm probably making a very obvious mistake.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: try if(first == true) and if ((secondorbefore == true)

Comment: @ZouZou, this should be answer:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

- `=` is an assignment operator.
- `==` is an equality operator.
- What happens when you use assignment operator in an if statement ??
- What happens when you use equalityoperator in an if statement ??

Comment: @Alnitak not in case of booleans though :)

Comment: even then, IMHO.  The common hint to the compiler to tell it you know what you're doing in other languages is to wrap the assignment in another pair of braces, i.e. `if ((var = true))`

Answer (score 4):

in `if`conditions you always have to use the `==` operator for comparison and *not* the single `=`.  So it would be:

```
if (first == true) {   // this is comparison
        first = false;  // this is assignment
        // DO STUFF FOR FIRST CLICK
 } else if ((secondorbefore == true) {
        //so this is the second click?
         secondorbefore = false;
        // DO STUFF FOR SECOND CLICK                
 } else {
        //OK it's the third click or later
        // DO STUFF FOR THIRD OR LATER CLICKS
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

if you use `=` instead of `==` you are assigning a value instead of comparing. And the return of the assingment is the value being assigned. So in that case it will be `true` So:

```
if(bool = true){...}
```

and

```
if(true){...}
```

are equivalent in the comparison. The difference is that `bool` will carry the new value from this statement on.

Answer (score 2):

change this  `if (first = true)`  to `{ if (first == true) {`

Here = is an assignment operator .But == is equality operator.

Answer (score 1):

When checking if a variable is equal to something else always use `==`

ie

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Check to see if this is the first click
    if (first == true) {
        first = false;
        // DO STUFF FOR FIRST CLICK
    } else if ((secondorbefore == true) {
        //so this is the second click?
        secondorbefore = false;
        // DO STUFF FOR SECOND CLICK                
    } else {
        //OK it's the third click or later
        // DO STUFF FOR THIRD OR LATER CLICKS
    }
}
```